# VBA Late Binding Delete Outlook Signature

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, late-binding

I have a section of code that is causing portability issues between Office 2013 and 2016 due to early vs late binding. I am trying to get this set as late binding to avoid having to uncheck the Word Object library that is of a higher version in the References library. I am unsure how to do this though.

```
'Function to Delete Auto Signature
 Public Function DelSig(olMsgReplyAll)
'Delete Automatic Signature

Dim ObjDoc As Word.Document
Dim oBookmark As Word.Bookmark
On Error Resume Next
Set ObjDoc = olMsgReplyAll.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set oBookmark = ObjDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
If Not oBookmark Is Nothing Then
    oBookmark.Select
    ObjDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
End If

DelSig = olMsgReplyAll
End Function
```

Comment: Dim everything `As Object` instead of what is shown in the code in the question.

Comment: When I do that, and even change set variables `Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, the function no longer works. I now have my default signature and one that is applied from another module as a global function.

Comment: Seeing as you don't even "Set" a Word object in the code you show us it's impossible to offer an opinion. We can only work with the information you provide <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

Late binding merely stands for "resolved at run-time".

When you declare something `As Word.Document`, you are resolving the types at compile-time, i.e. early binding: you know a member call is late-bound when you type the `.` dot and there's no intellisense dropdown popping up.

Declare the objects `As Object` or `As Variant`, and then the compiler will have no idea what types to use until run-time, and thus you'll have late-binding.

With all declarations late-bound, you can then remove the reference to the type library... but before you do that I would warmly recommend you make sure `Option Explicit` is specified in every module, because any constant or enum defined in that type library will otherwise no longer be defined, and will NOT be magically resolved at run-time - e.g. if you're using [`olFolderInbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) anywhere, you'll need to replace it with your own constant e.g. `Const olFolderInbox = 6`, otherwise `Outlook.olFolderInbox` won't be resolvable without the Outlook type library referenced, and you'll have a compile error.

Without `Option Explicit`, instead of a compile error, you'll have `olFolderInbox` silently "declared" at run-time as an implicit on-the-fly `Variant` with a value of `Empty`, which will silently convert to `0` wherever you're using it, which can lead to rather hard-to-diagnose problems.